dark chocolate 90% is looking pale brown and not dark brown why
I purchased 90% dark chocolate by AMUL India and kept in my car. on reaching home to my surprise the dark chocolate looked very brownish and the dark coating had nelted and accumulated in the botto of choc.Does dark chocolate-90% look so pale brownish. I thpught any dark choc above 75% would be dark brown fully and wholly. can anyone clear my doubt as i feel cheated by amul.

The "duplicate" is cold while this one is (evidently) heat, given the melted chocolate. Rest assured, the result is, indeed, still the same issue of migrating the cacao butter to the surface and losing the temper. Bring a cooler with cold packs when buying chocolate in hot weather, and either use this melted, or read up on tempering chocolate if you need it as solid chocolate.
